# how to do this dropdown with jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a jquery login drop down

I use this code to show the login `<div>`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.vv2').hover(function() {
        $('#boxa').slideDown('slow');                                                 
    });
});
```

I want to know how to hide it again if the user go away from the login area.

the code here 
http://www.sprnt.net/sprnt/

the first button in the top left screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.vv2').hover(function(){
      $('#boxa').slideDown('slow');                                                 
    }, function(){
      $('#boxa').slideUp('slow');
    });

});
```

When using hover, you can pass 2 functions, the first for mouseOver and the second for mouseOut.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.vv2').mouseout(function(){
            $('#boxa').slideUp('slow');                                                 
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy ref: [Hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) to handle mouse move
[jQuery slide Up](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [jQuery slide Down](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.vv2').hover(
    function() {
        $('#boxa').slideDown('slow');                                                 
    },
    function() {
        $('#boxa').slideUp('slow');                                                 
    }
);
});
```

just wanted to tell, hover event takes two functions. See here [jquery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)